# Move the whole vis network when dragging a node

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

When I'm dragging the network, it moves great and change the position of the 'camera' as intended. But when I dragging a node it moves the node. Can I make it move the whole 'camera' as if I did not press the node?

I tried to use the 'dragging' event but I couldn't make it behave perfect as I wanted it to.

Comment: "I try to use the 'dragging' event but ..." – could you share what you have tried and how that failed?

Comment: Well, I already deleted my tries. But the general rule is that I tried use network.moveTo while using event mouseDelta and mouse position and it allways worked wrong :( If I could send somehow the event as if there is no node selected, or I don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, it's quite simple to implement, just remove selection on dragStart:

```
var clearSelection = function(){
    network.unselectAll();
};
network.on('dragStart',clearSelection);
```

Worked for me in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ge2suzaw/). (I've also tried `network.on('selectNode',clearSelection);` – may be useful for UX but doesn't do what you need)

Comment: First of, I want to thank you so much for your time. I was afraid to be alone in this.
No, your solution works, BUT, unfortunately I cannot use it because I need the select event :((
Those are the events I'm subscribing to:
          network.on("blurNode", blurNode);
  network.on("selectNode", selectNodeEvent);
  network.on("dragging", selectNodeEvent);

Comment: @RanShaltiel not sure what's the problem. If you already have a handler for `dragStart`, just add the `network.unselectAll();` into it; you can do the same for `selectNode` if you really want to avoid the selection, but if you have other handlers, it's likely that you don't want to remove selection just on select. Anyway, you should describe ("design") the desired behaviour first and think about implementation next. If you want to elaborate this, you can ask another question (but be sure to include the code you already have into it).